# Modifying os.stat object

Tags: python

Is there a way to edit the object returned by os.stat?  At this point I'd like to be able to add a value for the filename to the object in order to identify the originating file easier.

At this point the only way I can figure out is to something like subclassing the posix.stat_result object and adding the value (though I haven't tried that to find out how doable that is).  Will that work? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert it to a `dict` this way:

```
import os
s = os.stat('.')
d = dict(zip('mode ino dev nlink uid gid size atime mtime ctime'.split(), s))
```

...and then add further entries to the `dict`.

Note that I included only the core 10 fields there.  If you want to cover [all the possible fields](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) then you could do something like:

```
import os
fields = 'mode ino dev nlink uid gid size atime mtime ctime blocks blksize rdev flags gen birthtime ftype attrs obtype'

s = os.stat('.')
d = dict((field,getattr(s,'st_'+field, None)) for field in fields.split())
```

Comment: Why not `d = {k: getattr(s, k) for k in dir(s) if k.startswith('st_')}` ? That way, you don't have to list the fields.

Comment: @phihag Good idea!